# In Python, how to replace a json subobject based on multiple attribute value settings?

Tags: json, python-3.x, replace

```
[
{
    "builtin_name": "custom_template",
    "fields": [
        {
            "id": 10012,
            "field_type": "OBJECT_SET",
            "tooltip_text": "",
            "name_plural": "",
            "name_singular": "reference",
            "backref_name": "reference",
            "backref_tooltip_text": "",
            "allow_multiple": false,
            "allowed_otypes": [
                "schema",
                "table",
                "attribute",
                "user",
                "groupprofile",
                "groupprofile"
            ],
            "options": null,
            "builtin_name": null
        },
        {
            "id": 8,
            "field_type": "OBJECT_SET",
            "tooltip_text": null,
            "name_plural": "Stewards",
            "name_singular": "Steward",
            "backref_name": "Steward",
            "backref_tooltip_text": null,
            "allow_multiple": true,
            "allowed_otypes": ["user", "groupprofile", "groupprofile"],
            "options": null,
            "builtin_name": "steward"
        }
    ],
    "id": 16,
    "title": "Custom template"
},
{
    "builtin_name": "new_template",
    "fields": [
        {
            "id": 10011,
            "field_type": "PICKER",
            "tooltip_text": "",
            "name_plural": "",
            "name_singular": "status",
            "backref_name": "",
            "backref_tooltip_text": "",
            "allow_multiple": false,
            "allowed_otypes": null,
            "options": [
                {
                    "old_index": 0,
                    "article_id": null,
                    "tooltip_text": null,
                    "in_use": true,
                    "title": "Done"
                }
            ],
            "builtin_name": null
        }
    ],
    "id": 1899,
    "title": "New Template"
}
```

]
Using this JSON object, I want to replace the `fields` list where `id=16 and title=Custom template`. I have already generated the object I want to use to the replacement.

Here's what I have tried, but didn't work:

```
i=0    
jdata_copy = jdata #this is so I can compare
for t in jdata:
    if(t["title"]=="Custom template" and t["id"]==16):            
        jdata_copy[i]["fields"] = repl_data
    i+=1
```

I've looked around for a simple json replace but haven't found.

Appreciate some help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, assuming this the python script is in the same directory as a json file called `test.json` and this is what the json looks like (not the same as yours since yours has both `null` and `None` values for some reason so I wasn't sure what to do with it):

```
[
    {
        "builtin_name": "custom_template",
        "fields": [
            {
                "id": 10012,
                "field_type": "OBJECT_SET",
                "tooltip_text": "",
                "name_plural": "",
                "name_singular": "reference",
                "backref_name": "reference",
                "backref_tooltip_text": "",
                "allow_multiple": false,
                "allowed_otypes": [
                    "schema",
                    "table",
                    "attribute",
                    "user",
                    "groupprofile",
                    "groupprofile"
                ],
                "options": null,
                "builtin_name": null
            },
            {
                "id": 8,
                "field_type": "OBJECT_SET",
                "tooltip_text": null,
                "name_plural": "Stewards",
                "name_singular": "Steward",
                "backref_name": "Steward",
                "backref_tooltip_text": null,
                "allow_multiple": true,
                "allowed_otypes": ["user", "groupprofile", "groupprofile"],
                "options": null,
                "builtin_name": "steward"
            }
        ],
        "id": 16,
        "title": "Custom template"
    },
    {
        "builtin_name": "new_template",
        "fields": [
            {
                "id": 10011,
                "field_type": "PICKER",
                "tooltip_text": "",
                "name_plural": "",
                "name_singular": "status",
                "backref_name": "",
                "backref_tooltip_text": "",
                "allow_multiple": false,
                "allowed_otypes": null,
                "options": [
                    {
                        "old_index": 0,
                        "article_id": null,
                        "tooltip_text": null,
                        "in_use": true,
                        "title": "Done"
                    }
                ],
                "builtin_name": null
            }
        ],
        "id": 1899,
        "title": "New Template"
    }
]
```

Then, this code works to load and change `fields`:

```
import json


with open("test.json") as json_file:
    jdata = json.load(json_file)

jdata_copy = jdata
```

for t in jdata:
if t["id"] == 16 and t["title"] == "Custom template":
pprint(jdata)
print()
t["fields"] = ["howdy", "hello"]
print()
pprint(jdata)

However let me know if this is the case for you, I wasn't sure from your question exactly what you were working with.

#### Edit

So, changing the code to:

```
import json
from pprint import pprint


with open("test.json") as json_file:
    jdata = json.load(json_file)

jdata_copy = jdata

for t in jdata:
    if t["id"] == 16 and t["title"] == "Custom template":
        pprint(jdata)

        t["fields"] = ["howdy", "hello"]

        pprint(jdata)
```

With this I can see that the first print statement returns the json as above just as a python dictionary, and the second print statement does indeed show jdata has had the `fields` section of the correct dictionary modified.

Then, I can export the dictionary back out to a `.json`:

```
with open("test1.json", "w") as json_file:
    json.dump(jdata, json_file)
```

This all works fine for me, which section here is not working for you? Sorry if I have misunderstood.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That doesn't work though. I had tried that.

Comment: Can you show how you are loading the json, and what is the json object etc. because the json data you provided above doesn't make much sense

Comment: I fixed and updated the original in my post above, it was an artifact of python that I didn't notice. Still doesn't make a difference about replacement though.

Comment: What do you mean by that though, after this what do you do with `jdata`? Do you export to json again?

Comment: I made an edit to the answer, please help me understand the issue you're having

Comment: Now that I've worked through it with your help, there was really no issue, it was my misunderstanding and I was replacing the wrong thing. Thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help you figure it out